# How to to compare numbers in a list, to the average of all the numbers in the same list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

def average():
    infile = open("pa8_numbers.py")
    global mylist
    mylist = []
    num = infile.readline()
    while num != "":
        mylist.append(eval(num))

        num = infile.readline()

    Sum = 0

    for x in mylist:
        Sum = x + Sum
    global avg

    avg = Sum/10000

    print("Average: ", end=''), print(format(avg, '.2f'))
```

These I don't know about, I know it's having trouble getting 'avg' and 'mylist' from of def, but I'm really bad at object oriented programming. Is there a work around?

```
def above(mylist, avg):
    acount = 0

    abv = avg + 10

    for a in mylist:
        if a in range(eval(avg, abv)):
            count = count + 1
    print(acount)

def below(mylist, avg):
    bcount = 0
    blw = avg - 10

    for a in mylist:
        if a in range(avg, blw):
            count = count + 1
    print(bcount)

def main():

    outfile = open("pa8_numbers.py","w") 

    for i in range(10000):

        data = random.randint(1,100)

        outfile.write(str(data)+"\n") 

    outfile.close()

    print("Statistics")
    print("---------------------")


    average()

    above(mylist, avg)

    below(mylist, avg)


main()
```

The goal is to make a list of 100 random numbers, sum those numbers and find the avg. The compare the list of random numbers to the avg+10 and avg-10.

And Count how many random number from the list fall in the category avg+10 and avg-10.

Please help, thanks

Comment: I really suggest you to try and learn how to program. You won't get any answers by asking vague questions. You are saying that you are bad at object oriented programming but your code is not even object oriented to begin with.

Comment: I am trying to learn, I have trouble formulating questions about programming. It's literally a language. If someone had a question about learning to speak English would you just tell them to just speak English better?                                              I know I should be using object oriented programming to do this and put everything into classes, but I honestly don't understand it. I am more comfortable with loops and such.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import random

data = random.sample(range(1, 200), 100)
print(data)
avg = sum(data) / len(data)
print(avg)
print([i for i in data if (i >= avg) and (i <= avg + 10)])
print([i for i in data if (i < avg) and (i >= avg - 10)])
```

Sample output

```
[8, 54, 13, 60, 156, 152, 128, 89, 28, 142, 197, 37, 109, 133, 44, 45, 57, 194, 106, 95, 39, 85, 82, 27, 25, 64, 102, 143, 99, 61, 43, 118, 182, 141, 117, 15, 78, 6, 164, 132, 86, 19, 77, 186, 97, 119, 154, 63, 48, 122, 14, 53, 7, 83, 90, 136, 163, 76, 148, 196, 190, 150, 4, 66, 180, 165, 38, 130, 32, 94, 170, 140, 36, 96, 176, 62, 167, 179, 172, 127, 79, 17, 16, 139, 116, 34, 30, 9, 40, 195, 111, 115, 146, 80, 193, 58, 51, 125, 93, 98]
96.26
[106, 102, 99, 97, 98]
[89, 95, 90, 94, 96, 93]
```

Comment: `print([n for n in data if abs(n - avg) <= 10])`

Comment: Thought (s)he wanted in seperate lists

Answer (score 0):

import random

def average():
    infile = open("pa8_numbers.py")

```
mylist = []
num = infile.readline()
while num != "":
    mylist.append(eval(num))

    num = infile.readline()

Sum = 0

for x in mylist:
    Sum = x + Sum

avg = Sum/10000

print("Average: ", end=''), print(format(avg, '.2f'))
return avg
```

def above():
    acount = 0

```
infile = open("pa8_numbers.py")

mylist = []
num = infile.readline()
while num != "":
    mylist.append(eval(num))

    num = infile.readline()

Sum = 0

for x in mylist:
    Sum = x + Sum

avg = Sum//10000

abv = avg + 10

for a in mylist:
    if a in range(avg, abv):
        acount += 1

print("Above10: ", acount)
```

def below():
    bcount = 0

```
infile = open("pa8_numbers.py")

mylist = []
num = infile.readline()
while num != "":
    mylist.append(eval(num))

    num = infile.readline()

Sum = 0

for x in mylist:
    Sum = x + Sum

avg = Sum//10000

blw = avg - 10

for a in mylist:
    if a in range(blw, avg):
        bcount += 1

print("Below10: ", bcount)
```

def main():

```
outfile = open("pa8_numbers.py","w") 

for i in range(10000):

    data = random.randint(1,100)

    outfile.write(str(data)+"\n") 

outfile.close()

print("Statistics")
print("---------------------")


average()

above()

below()
```

main()

Instead of trying to access avg that was definied earlier in the average function, I just copied and pasted it's code and plugged it in. I know its ugly, and not pretty. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import numpy as np

num = 25  #Choose the number of random numbers
arr = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(num,))  #Numpy array of random numbers
lst = list(arr)  #Convert array to list
print lst

>>> [54.5319505485215, 4.245083725270494, 78.678755233104, 13.350267097985968, 0.053831517325253486, 41.35195665558887, 32.247355069096336, 49.18231116527674, 94.7134275426869, 82.70659951321971, 69.20538155428206, 47.5556647970394, 70.51752770999894, 34.769182788859574, 35.32276275010964, 4.087762606868672, 83.63591325576411, 64.02551476912747, 33.82182179701143, 79.41086468884642, 83.315665673576, 38.115224599910604, 21.318686272968367, 37.495943736007376, 19.8111480759137]

arr_mean = np.mean(arr) #Mean of the array/list of random numbers
print arr_mean

>>> 46.93882412577438

''' Array (arr_new) of random numbers with (arr_mean-10, arr_mean+10) '''
arr_new = arr[ (np.where( (arr<arr_mean+10) & (arr>arr_mean-10)  )[0] ) ]
print arr_new

>>> [54.53195055 41.35195666 49.18231117 47.5556648  38.1152246  37.49594374]

''' Print mean and length of new array. '''
print "Length of new array is: ", len(arr_new)
print "Mean of new array is: ", np.mean(arr_new)

>>> Length of new array is:  6
>>> Mean of new array is:  44.70550858372409
```